# Parameter for addEventListener doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, addeventlistener

I am creating a "slideshow" if you will call it that, for page navigation.

I am attempting to use a forloop to add an eventlistener to all menu items. And it doesn't seem to work. Basically i have a function that shows a new page, based on a parameter.

```
function slidePFer(page_side){
```

And this works perfectly by setting the eventlisteners manually like this:

```
showPF  = document.getElementsByClassName('showPF');

showPF[0].addEventListener('click', function(){ slidePFer(0); }, false);
showPF[1].addEventListener('click', function(){ slidePFer(1); }, false);
showPF[2].addEventListener('click', function(){ slidePFer(2); }, false);
showPF[3].addEventListener('click', function(){ slidePFer(3); }, false);
```

This looks however very messy. So i attempted to run though it all with different loops. And i just can't make it work, here is one of the more promissing loops i have tried:

```
for(var i=0, n=showPF.length; i<n; i++){
    showPF[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ slidePFer(i); }, false);
}
```

Can anybody see what i appear to not understand?

Comment: Still looking for the correct answer, if anybody knows it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove i from function(i) Maybe this will fix it

Comment: tried that. I added the "i" to see if that was my mistake but it wasn't thx however for the tip :)

Comment: Also what is the value of swatches? Maybe it must be showPF .length

Comment: Naah its not value of swatches. Its an array. i have done this before but not with addeventlisteners.

Comment: you should add this line `alert(swatches.length);` line above the for loop to check if your array has a length.

Comment: I know the .length works. Because i did that alert long time ago :) was thinking the same as you are now. But that is not the problem either

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery (http://jquery.com), you can simplify this like this:

html

```
<img slideNo="0" class="showPF" src="slide_0_preview.jpg" />
<img slideNo="1" class="showPF" src="slide_1_preview.jpg" />
<img slideNo="2" class="showPF" src="slide_2_preview.jpg" />
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.showPF').click(function() {
            slidePFer($(this).attr('slideNo'));
        });
    });
    function slidePFer(slideNo) {
        // todo
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Should have probably stated that i am doing this without jQuery. thx however for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution myself for anyone interested this is how i did it:

```
showPF          = document.getElementsByClassName('showPF');

var i = showPF.length;
    while(i--){
        showPF[i].addEventListener('click', function(x){ return function(){ slidePFer(x); }; }(i),false);
    }
```

Credit where credit does: 
http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside-a